# Recursively peek a map to get its values in Clojure

Tags: recursion, clojure

I'm trying to write a function which will recursively pop a map in order to get a value out, one at a time.

The following is what I've got so far..

```
(defrecord Stoptest [&args])

(def test (Stoptest. [:c101 :main-office :a1]))

(defn stopPop [x]
 (peek (-> x :&args))
 (recur(peek(rest x))))

(stopPop test)
```

I get an error saying the following:

```
clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IPersistentStack
```

What's causing this issue?

Cheers

Comment: Better suited to [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Thumbnail Um, no? Judging by the error message, it doesn't seem like the code in this question qualifies as "working".

Comment: @SamEstep That's certainly true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rest` returns not a vector but a lazy seq. The error appears when you try to `peek` on in:

`(peek (seq [1 2 3]))
;; gives the same error`

The problem happens here because you have different type objects on each step of recursion. On the top, you have `Stoptest` instance. Next, you have a lazy sequence that behaves in other way.

I don't see any reason here to wrap your vector into a typed record. You can always iterate on the vector easily.

Comment: Okay, im using defrecord as i want to be able to call it later on. The whole 'task' will look as such, (def task6 (Robot. :main-office (Stops. :r131 :main-office nil nil) :r111 (Packages. ["Notepad", "Shoes"] [0.1 1]) false)) which is then passed to a method. Is there a way for me to iterate the typed record?

Comment: `
(doseq [arg (:&args test)] 
   (println arg))

:c101
:main-office
:a1
nil
`

Comment: btw you write Clojure like Java. personally I'd keep your data (robots, packages etc) just in plain data structures like vectors and maps.

Comment: Okay, thank you, ill work on changing it over. That works perfectly, is there a way in which i can assign the values to different variables over printing them?